# How can i get all classes in a class?

Tags: java, oop

I have a class like this:

```
public class ClassList {

    public class SubClassOne {

    }

    public class SubClassTwo {

    }

}
```

Now i want to have a list of all classes in my ClassList class without having to add them all by hand. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried Class.getDeclaredClasses()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You may use [`Class.getClasses()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClasses--)

> Returns an array containing Class objects representing all the public classes and interfaces that are members of the class represented by this Class object. **ONLY** `public` modifier

- or  [`Class.getDeclaredClasses()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses--)

> Returns an array of Class objects reflecting all the classes and interfaces declared as members of the class represented by this Class object. **All** `(public, protected, default (package), private)` modifiers

---

```
Class<ClassList> classList = ClassList.class;
Class<?>[] classes = classList.getClasses();
for (Class<?> c : classes) {
    System.out.println(c.getName());
}

packageName.ClassList$SubClassTwo
packageName.ClassList$SubClassOne
```